# Convert Duplicate Finder Query to Drop All But the Newest Record

Tags: mysql

I have a duplicate finder query...

```
SELECT
    Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    db.table
GROUP BY
    Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

It returns those records which are duplicates, and the count of how many there are.

I would like to extend this so that it drops all but the latest version of each duplicate(s). I guess we could use `id` or `datetime` field which I have available in the table for identifying which records to keep. Or is there another way?

Edit: I'm half way there...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    db.table
GROUP BY
    Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    Name, TrackNum
```

The above seems to show one copy of each duplicate. When I delete them in workbench I'm only left with the remaining, latest unique records. I'd just like to automate this one step further. Also this doesn't account for more than two identical records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
#
# Step 01) Create Temp Key Tables
#
CREATE TABLE KeysToKeep
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE KeysToDrop LIKE KeysToKeep;
#
# Step 02) Collect All id values you want to Keep
#
INSERT INTO KeysToKeep
    SELECT id FROM
    (SELECT MAX(id) id,Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id
    FROM db.table GROUP BY Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id) A
;
#
# Step 03) Collect All id values you want to Drop
#
INSERT INTO KeysToDrop
SELECT A.id FROM db.table A LEFT JOIN KeysToKeep USING (id) WHERE B.id IS NULL;
#
# Step 04) Do the Mass Delete 
#
DELETE A.* FROM db.table A INNER JOIN KeysToDrop B USING (id);
#
# Step 05) Remove Temp Key Tables
#
DROP TABLE KeysToKeep;
DROP TABLE KeysToDrop;
```

## PROPOSED SOLUTION (Shorter Version)

```
#
# Step 01) Create Temp Key Table
#
CREATE TABLE KeysToKeep
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
#
# Step 02) Collect All id values you want to Keep
#
INSERT INTO KeysToKeep
    SELECT id FROM
    (SELECT MAX(id) id,Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id
    FROM db.table GROUP BY Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id) A
;
#
# Step 03) Do the Mass Delete 
#
DELETE A.* FROM db.table A LEFT JOIN KeysToKeep B USING (id) WHERE B.id IS NULL;
#
# Step 04) Remove Temp Key Table
#
DROP TABLE KeysToKeep;
```

## PROPOSED SOLUTION (Paranoid Version)

```
#
# Step 01) Create Temp Key Table
#
CREATE TABLE KeysToKeep
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
#
# Step 02) Collect All id values you want to Keep
#
INSERT INTO KeysToKeep
    SELECT id FROM
    (SELECT MAX(id) id,Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id
    FROM db.table GROUP BY Author, Name, TrackNum, title_id) A
;
#
# Step 03) Copy the Tables to Keep to Another Temp Table
#
CREATE TABLE db.table_new LIKE db.table;
INSERT INTO db.table_new
SELECT A.* FROM db.table A INNER JOIN KeysToKeep B USING (id);
#
# Step 04) Swap New and Old Tables
#
ALTER TABLE db.table RENAME db.table_old;
ALTER TABLE db.table_new RENAME db.table;
#
# Step 05) Remove Temp Key Table
#
DROP TABLE KeysToKeep;
#
# Step 06) Drop the Old Table If the Content of db.table is Correct
#
DROP TABLE db.table_old;
```

## EPILOGUE

In the first two cases, check `KeysToKeep` and/or `KeysToDrop` to make sure they are the keys to keep or drop. In the last case, drop the table `db.table_old` if you are sure. If you are not sure, you can roll it back like this:

```
ALTER TABLE db.table RENAME db.table_new;
ALTER TABLE db.table_old RENAME db.table;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY!

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful response. I'm just working through it now in a test environment. I tried the paranoid version. First I replaced all occurrences of db with my db name. I got a syntax error so removed an extra `;`. Then I got an error `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias`. Any ideas?

Comment: OK tried that, now I get this error... `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO KeysToKeep
    SELECT id FROM
    (SELECT MAX(id) id,Author, Name, T' at line 12` Note I removed an extra semicolon that I mentioned before (Line 7).

Comment: Actually, I tried again and it seems to work:) I must have missed a table reference.

Comment: Also are you able to clarify the difference between the versions? The paranoid version seems to be the opposite, in that there is no way to undo the changes. Just wondering why you called it that.

Comment: I called it paranoid because of the fear of losing the data in case the `ALTER TABLE` could not be rolled back. The paranoid version simply keeps a copy of the table in its original state before Step 04.